# The total number of downloads in the Google Play Store differs from the total number of downloads in the Google Play Console

Tags: google-play, google-play-console

In Google Play Console, the total number of unique users who have installed my app is 82.
And in the Google Play Store, the number of downloads is +10.
+50 was expected.
The first download that broke the 50-download barrier was 12 days ago
So what is the reason?

The expected number of downloads in the Google Play Store is +50.
Thank you.

Comment: maybe the clue is on the terminology used? **unique users** and **download** should refer to two different things. i have no clue if this question best addressed in stackoverflow or not, but i do feel its best to be asked to google themself.